# Order of definition of constrainsts and concepts c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Where is the right position of a concept or constraint?

The following code compile:

```
void f(int x) { } 

template <typename T>
concept Concept =
    requires (T a)
    { f(a); };


template <typename T>
    requires Concept<T>
struct A
{ };



int main(){
    A<int> a;
}
```

but if I change the position of the function `f(int)` to:

```
template <typename T>
concept Concept =
    requires (T a)
    { f(a); };


void f(int x) { } // <-- new position

template <typename T>
    requires Concept<T>
struct A
{ };



int main(){
    A<int> a;
}
```

this doesn't compile in gcc 11.3.0. I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:27:10: error: template constraint failure for ‘template<class T>  requires  Concept<T> struct A’
   27 |     A<int> a;
      |          ^
main.cpp:27:10: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T>  requires  Concept<T> struct A [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:27:10:   required from here
main.cpp:12:9:   required for the satisfaction of ‘Concept<T>’ [with T = int]
main.cpp:13:5:   in requirements with ‘T a’ [with T = int]
main.cpp:14:8: note: the required expression ‘f(a)’ is invalid
   14 |     { f(a); };
```

Answer (score 7):

If a function is declared after a template, the only way the template can call it is via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). `int` is a built-in type, so ADL doesn't happen for it.

If the parameter was e.g. a class type, defined in the same namespace as `f()`, it would work.

Clang explains this:

`...`
`<source>:5:7: note: because 'f(a)' would be invalid: call to function 'f' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup`

Answer (score 0):

It works if you predeclare the function. It is not defined at that point in the file.

It's the same principle as when calling functions, you need a predeclaration to be able to use it without seeing the definition.

```
void f(int x);

template <typename T>
concept Concept =
    requires (T a)
    { f(a); };


void f(int x) { } // <-- new position

template <typename T>
    requires Concept<T>
struct A
{ };



int main(){
    A<int> a;
}
```